# BIRT report won't print dataSetRow["name"] value when run in birt-report plugin

Tags: grails, birt

I have created a simple BIRT report that selects data from two DB tables using two different DataSets. It also has got two parameters that are passed into DataSet queries.

My problem is that when I run the report from the Eclipse+BIRT environment it fetches all the data as it should, but when I run the report from a Grails birt-report service, it prints only the static skeleton, but not the data from DB.

First I thought that something was wrong with the parameter values I passed to the service, so I added a line to the report that printed those values. The params were passd and printed as they should.
Then I removed the *where* part from my queries, but still nothing happened. The report is filled in when run from Eclipse and is empty when run in a *birt-report* plugin.

This is the code I use to print a report:

```
    params.remove('action')
    params.remove('controller')
    params.remove('name')

    params.put("userId", 10)   //parameter that should be passed
    params.put("resumeId", 5)  //parameter that should be passed

    println params;

    def options = birtReportService.getRenderOption(request, 'doc')
    def result=birtReportService.runAndRender(reportName, params, options)
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +reportName + "."+reportExt);
    response.contentType = 'application/doc'
    response.outputStream << result.toByteArray()
```

Any ideas what might be the reason?

UPD: How can I debug it to see what's really going on inside?

UPD 2: looks like it has something to do with the app, cause when I launch the report in a new Grails application it works fine.

The only difference between successful and failed launches that I found when looking through debug logs is this:

**my app log:**

```
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery] [219] ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl@1ed14cb8 org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.QueryDefinition@729b6def org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.OdaDataSetAdapter@200ecb05 {org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.util_consumerResourceIds=org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.util.ResourceIdentifiers@2b32c5b4, OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection=Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection  from DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@39547eb6], HTML_RENDER_CONTEXT=org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderContext@1251c294, org.eclipse.birt.data.query.ResultBufferSize=100}
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl] [219] PreparedQuery starts up.
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.aggregation.AggregateTable] [219] ENTRY
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.aggregation.AggregateTable] [219] RETURN
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.aggregation.AggregateTable] [219] ENTRY C:\Users\SZAGOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\DataEngine_517033144_2\ [object Object] []
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.aggregation.AggregateTable] [219] RETURN
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl] [219] Start to prepare a PreparedQuery.
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.aggregation.AggrRegistry] [219] ENTRY 0 -1 true org.eclipse.birt.core.script.ScriptContext@57b32816
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.aggregation.AggrRegistry] [219] RETURN

//these lines are suspicious
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,909][org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.InvalidExpression] [219] InvalidExpression starts up
[26/03/2013 13:12:36,912] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.InvalidExpression] [219] InvalidExpression starts up

[26/03/2013 13:12:36,912] [org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.GroupBindingColumn] [219] ENTRY null 0 {first_name=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.Binding@f6678eba, last_name=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.Binding@77fdce94, coalesce(resume.mobile_phone, " - ")=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.Binding@9beadc7d}
```

**and the new app log:**

```
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery  - ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl@79bff971 org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.QueryDefinition@1799e2e2 org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.OdaDataSetAdapter@1aec9361 {org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.util_consumerResourceIds=org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.util.ResourceIdentifiers@21bfd316, OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection=Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection  from DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@38bb5aa9], HTML_RENDER_CONTEXT=org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderContext@143d2a58, org.eclipse.birt.data.query.ResultBufferSize=100}
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG impl.DataEngineImpl  - PreparedQuery starts up.
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG aggregation.AggregateTable  - ENTRY
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG aggregation.AggregateTable  - RETURN
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG aggregation.AggregateTable  - ENTRY C:\Users\SZAGOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\DataEngine_2042624369_1\ [object Object] []
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG aggregation.AggregateTable  - RETURN
2013-03-26 12:51:08,352 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG impl.DataEngineImpl  - Start to prepare a PreparedQuery.
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG aggregation.AggrRegistry  - ENTRY 0 -1 true org.eclipse.birt.core.script.ScriptContext@560fc912
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG aggregation.AggrRegistry  - RETURN

// here it's different
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG expression.ColumnReferenceExpression  - ENTRY first_name
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG expression.ColumnReferenceExpression  - RETURN
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG expression.ColumnReferenceExpression  - ENTRY last_name
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG expression.ColumnReferenceExpression  - RETURN
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG expression.ColumnReferenceExpression  - ENTRY coalesce(resume.mobile_phone, " - ")
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG expression.ColumnReferenceExpression  - RETURN
2013-03-26 12:51:08,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG impl.GroupBindingColumn  - ENTRY null 0 {first_name=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.Binding@f6678eba, last_name=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.Binding@77fdce94, coalesce(resume.mobile_phone, " - ")=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn.Binding@9beadc7d}
```

The same report file was used in both cases.

Comment: I am not familiar with Grails, but. Are you getting any errors showing on Grails? If you run a simular report on Grails does it work ok?

Comment: @JamesJenkins, There are no Grails errors or any other errors coming up and this is the first BIRT report I've ever created, so I can't really tell if others work.

Comment: I would create a simple report using the demo data "Classic Cars" there are tutorials in the BIRT help interface.  Then test it through Grail.  This should help you figure out if the error is on the BIRT side or the Grail side (or the joining of them).  Because the classic cars data is in the BIRT product, it bypasses the DB connection.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, turns out that it doesn't print any of the *Classic models* as well while working in the Eclipse preview. Is there a way to embed a logger into the report to make it print all the errors?

Comment: @JamesJenkins, Well, this has something to do with my Grails app, cause when I launch the report in a newly created Grails application, it works.

Comment: your at the end of my ability to help.  Good luck